# Count the number of number x that has digit sum equal the digit sum of x*m

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, dynamic-programming

I was trying to solve the following problem but I am stuck. I think it is an dynamic programming problem.
Could you please give some ideas?

Problem:

Given a positive number n (n<=18) and a positive number m (m<=100). 
Call S(x) is sum of digits of x.
For example S(123)=6
Count the number of integer number x that has n digits and S(x)=S(x*m)

Example:

n= 1, m= 2 result= 2

n= 18, m=1  result = 1000000000000000000

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. I seems not to be well-posed. In your first example: x=2, S(x)=S(2)=2; S(x*m)=S(4)=4, which violates S(x)=S(x*m). In the second case, with m=1, any number with n digits would be a solution.

Comment: I would be very surprised if DP would work here. Why do you think it would work here? First, I would look for some rules/patterns. For example, divisibility by 9, depending on (m modulo 9) you can automatically limit the possible values. Of course if m=1,10,100 then the answer is obvious. The answer for m = k*10 is the same as for m = k. Still for n = 18, I don't see any way to solve this before end of the universe.

Comment: @isanco. The result is 2 because `[0, 9]` are possible answers.

Comment: @Washington Guedes. Thanks, I get it now.

Comment: http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum0.htm  has some digit sum properties, ii really seems like (though doubtful) the result to a problem like this could be calculated directly.

Comment: @LouisRicci. Very interesting article, I think I got the way to calculate it directly, I made one community wiki answer with some content about it. Feel free to improve it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, we need to come up with a recursive formula:

Starting from the least significant digit (LSD) to the most significant digit (MSD), we have a valid solution if after we compute the MSD, we have `S(x) = S(x*m)`

To verify  whether a number is a valid solution, we need to know three things:

- What is the current sum of digit S(x)
- What is the current sum of digit S(x*m)
- What is the current digit.

So, to answer for the first and last, it is easy, we just need to maintain two parameters `sum`and `digit`. To compute the second, we need to maintain two additional parameters, `sumOfProduct` and `lastRemaining`.

- `sumOfProduct` is the current S(x*m)
- `lastRemaining` is the result of `(m * current digit value + lastRemaining) / 10`

For example, we have `x = 123` and `m = 23`

- First digit = 3

  ```
  sum = 3
  digit  = 0
  sumOfProduct += (lastRemaining + 3*m) % 10 = 9
  lastRemaining = (m*3 + 0)/10 = 6
  ```
- Second digit = 2

  ```
  sum = 5
  digit = 1
  sumOfProduct += (lastRemaining + 2*m) % 10 = 11
  lastRemaining = (m*2 + lastRemaining)/10 = 5
  ```
- Last digit = 1

  ```
  sum = 6
  digit = 2
  sumOfProduct += (lastRemaining + m) % 10 = 19
  lastRemaining = (m + lastRemaining)/10 = 2
  ```

  As this is the last digit, `sumOfProduct += S(lastRemaining) = 21`.

So, `x = 123` and `m = 23` is not a valid number. Check `x*m = 2829 -> S(x*m) = S(2829) = 21`.

So, we can have a recursive formula with state `(digit, sum, sumOfProdut, lastRemaining)`.

Thus, our dynamic programming state is `dp[18][18*9 + 1][18*9 + 1][200]` (as m <= 100, so `lastRemaining` not larger than  200).

Now the `dp`state is over 300 MB, but if we use an iterative approach, it will become smaller, using about 30MB

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be calculated directly.

From those documents: [1](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum0.htm), [2](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum1.htm), and [3](http://www.sjsu.edu/faculty/watkins/Digitsum2.htm) *(thanks to [@LouisRicci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/884862/louis-ricci) for finding them)*, we can state:

1. The Repeating Cycle of Sum of Digits of Multiples starts repeating at the last digit but one from the base-number (9 for base-10)
2. `S(x)` can be defined as: let `a` equal `x mod 9`, if `a` is zero, take `9` as result, else take `a`. *You can play it in the ES6 snippet below:*

```js
IN.oninput= (_=> OUT.value= (IN.value % 9) || 9);
IN.oninput();
```

```html
Input x:<br>
<input id=IN value=123><br>

S(x):<br>
<input id=OUT disabled>
```

3. Multiplication rule: `S(x * y) = S(S(x) * S(y))`.
4. `S(x)` and `S(x*m)` will always be true for `x=0`, this way there is no zero result.

---

With the above statements in mind, we should calc the Repeating Cycle of Sum of Digits of Multiples for `S(m)`:

```
int m = 88;
int Sm = S(m); // 7

int true_n_times_in_nine = 0;
for (int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
    true_n_times_in_nine += i == S(i * Sm);
}
```

The answer then:

```
result = ((pow(10, n) / 9) * true_n_times_in_nine);
```

Plus one because of case zero:

```
result++;
```

Here is an ES6 solution:

```js
S= x=> (x % 9) || 9;
TrueIn9= (m, Sm=S(m))=> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].filter(i=> i==S(i*Sm)).length;
F= (n,m)=> ~~(eval('1e'+n)/9) * TrueIn9(m) + 1;


N.oninput= 
M.oninput= 
f=(_=> OUT.value= F(N.value | 0, M.value | 0));
f();
```

```html
Input n: (number of digits)<br>
<input id=N value=1><br>

Input m: (multiplicative number)<br>
<input id=M value=2><br>

F(n,m):<br>
<input id=OUT disabled><br>
```